# Open link from lightbox2 image data-title without shadow overlay?

Tags: html, hyperlink, overlay, lightbox2

I got a link to an orderform in my data-title image description. Unfortunatedly when it opens the page keeps the lightbox2 shadow overlay on top. The layer disapears if I click somewhere. Is there a way to breakout direct without clicking?

```
<a class="tile-inner" data-title="Text <a href='index.html#orderform' style='color:#EB590E;font-style:italic;font-weight:bold;'>Order now!</a>" data-lightbox="gallery" href="img/big/7.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I ended up with adding `onclick='parent.window.location.reload();'` and some variables (for the orderform preselect) to the link.